# How to round corners on polar plot in Java?

Tags: java, plot, jfreechart

I've created polar plot using JFreeChart with two data series: initial (red) and modified (blue). The modified data series has sharp corners that need to be smoothed out, as shown in the figure below. I tried to use moving average, but it didn't work properly. This is my plot:

[image: polar plot]

Also i tried to do interpolation but it also didn't work.

```
public void interpolate(Map<Double, Double> data) {
    double angel = 0.0;
    double increment = reader.getPolarAngelsArray()[1];
    int length = reader.getNumberOfPolarAngels() * 2 - 1;
    double[] x = new double[length];
    double[] y = new double[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        x[i] = angel;
        y[i] = data.get(angel);
        angel += increment;
    }
    UnivariateInterpolator interpolator = new SplineInterpolator();
    UnivariateFunction function = interpolator.interpolate(x, y);
    for (double angle = 0.0; angle <= 360.0; angle += increment) {
        data.put(angle, function.value(angle));
    }
}
```

moving average:

```
public XYSeries movAvg(XYSeries series) {

    ArrayList<Double> avgY = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < series.getItemCount(); i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            avgY.add((Double) series.getY(i));
        } else if (i == (series.getItemCount() - 1)) {
            avgY.add((Double) series.getY(i));
        } else {
            avgY.add(((Double) series.getY(i - 1) +
                    (Double) series.getY(i) +
                    (Double) series.getY(i + 1)) / 3.0);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < series.getItemCount(); i++) {
        series.update(series.getX(i), avgY.get(i));
    }
    return series;
}
```

After using moving average method the situation is getting better but sharp corners are keeping. [After moving average](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Nomm.jpg).

The sample data: angels: 25.0 27.5 30.0 32.5 35.0 37.5 40.0 42.5 45.0 47.5 50.0 52.5 55.0 57.5 60.0 62.5 65.0 values: 327.24 321.03 314.3 307.05 298.64 290.09 280.77 270.14 511.27 488.73 463.07 438.02 411.86 382.51 354.24 324.84 290.96

Comment: A part of a dataset with a sharp corner and a code to calculate a moving average could help to detect the problem.

Comment: A part with dataset is ok. The moving average gives a stepwise result. Are there other mathematical ways to make this smoother?

Comment: There are many ways to make a graph smooth. For example, splines. However, moving average should do a trick here as well. That's why I asked for the part of data and the code, because there might be some problem hidden there.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that illustrates the problem you describe and what "didn't work properly."

Comment: I've added interpolation method from The Apache Commons Mathematics Library in body question. This method also didn't work.

Comment: More on splines is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjfreechart%5D+spline).

Comment: It seems that the density of points in your dataset is very large. The moving average in the posted code is averaging just 3 neighbour points, so it doesn't help much. You need to adjust the size of the moving average window. If you provide a part of the dataset near one of the sharp corners it will be easier to detect the problem.

Comment: The sample data: angels: 25.0 27.5 30.0 32.5 35.0 37.5 40.0 42.5 45.0 47.5 50.0 52.5 55.0 57.5 60.0 62.5 65.0
values: 327.24 321.03 314.3 307.05 298.64 290.09 280.77 270.14 511.27 488.73 463.07 438.02 411.86 382.51 354.24 324.84 290.96

Comment: @Eugene: Please [edit] your question to show the data, ideally as a [mre].